# Call a function with arguments from a list

Tags: scala

Is there a way to call a function with arguments from a list? The equivalent in Python is `sum(*args)`.

```
// Scala

def sum(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
val args = List(1, 4)

sum.???(args)      // equivalent to sum(1, 4)
```

`sum(args: _*)` wouldn't work here.
Don't offer change the declaration of the function anyhow. I'm acquainted with a function with repeated parameters `def sum(args: Int*)`.

Comment: You say not to offer the change in declaration yet the Python's "equivalent" have a changed declaration.

Comment: @ArtemGr: As I know in Python you don't have to change the code of the function to use it in this way `func(*list_of_args)`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, got it now.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the types of the arguments differ and so can't be in a List?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can write

```
sum(args(0), args(1))
```

But I assume you want this to work for any list length? Then you would go for `fold` or `reduce`:

```
args.reduce(sum)  // args must be non empty!

(0 /: args)(sum)  // aka args.foldLeft(0)(sum)
```

These methods assume a pair-wise reduction of the list. For example, `foldLeft[B](init: B)(fun: (B, A) => B): B` reduces a list of elements of type `A` to a single element of type `B`. In this example, `A = B = Int`. It starts with the initial value `init`. Since you want to sum, the sum of an empty list would be zero. It then calls the function with the current accumulator (the running sum) and each successive element of the list.

So it's like

```
var result = 0
result = sum(result, 1)
result = sum(result, 4)
...
```

---

The `reduce` method assumes that the list is non-empty and requires that the element type doesn't change (the function must map from two `Int`s to an `Int`).

Comment: Could you add a bit of reasoning why `foldLeft` works here in the intended way.

Comment: I assume the OP wants this to work with any function, not just sum. Invoke a function and pass a sequence/tuple of arguments.

Comment: What would you do if the function `sum` takes three arguments? And as I understand there is no alternative to the Python mmethod. You have to use functional programming?

Comment: By definition, collections are variable arity, so there is no general approach to unpack collections into a non-variable arity method. Honestly, such scenario is rather esoteric, anyway. If you know your arity, use tuples instead of lists. If you want to combine both, you can use a rather large hammer such as Shapeless which provides collections whose size is known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it for most uses since it's a bit complicated and hard to read, bypasses compile-time checks, etc., but if you know what you're doing and need to do this, you can use reflection.  This should work with any arbitary parameter types.  For example, here's how you might call a constructor with arguments from a list:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

class MyClass(
  val field1: String,
  val field2: Int,
  val field3: Double)

// Get our runtime mirror
val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

// Get the MyClass class symbol
val classSymbol = universe.typeOf[MyClass].typeSymbol.asClass

// Get a class mirror for the MyClass class
val myClassMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)

// Get a MyClass constructor representation
val myClassCtor = universe.typeOf[MyClass].decl(universe.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod

// Get an invokable version of the constructor
val myClassInvokableCtor = myClassMirror.reflectConstructor(myClassCtor)

val myArgs: List[Any] = List("one", 2, 3.0)

val myInstance = myClassInvokableCtor(myArgs: _*).asInstanceOf[MyClass]
```